# Crossinheritance in C#

Tags: c#, architecture, class-design

I am looking for the best way to model a scenario in C#, which I would describe as "crossinheritance".

First, I have a directed graph, which nodes can be of two different types: **Connector** and **Component**. I create an interface **IObjectBase** which contains properties both Connector and Component have, like a list of IObjectBase-Children. Then I create interfaces for the Connectors and Components which inherited from IObjectBase:

```
public interface IObjectConnector : IObjectBase ...
public interface IObjectComponent : IObjectBase ...
```

The implementation looks similar, I create an abstract class for the BaseObject and inherit it for Connector and Component classes:

```
public abstract class ObjectBase : IObjectBase ...
public class ObjectConnector : ObjectBase, IObjectConnector ...
public class ObjectComponent : ObjectBase, IObjectComponent ...
```

So far so good. The problem is, that the directed graph can exist in two different "states" or "modes" - in **Editor-Mode** and in **Configuration-Mode**. Depending on the mode, there are Properties and methods Connectors and Components both have (like adding children only when in editor-mode or a "isSelected" property only when in configurator-mode).

So, I would need to have 4 different objects: **ComponentConfig**, **ComponentEdit**, **ConnectorConfig**, **ConnectorEdit**

I started with thinking about further inherit IObjectConnector and IObjectComponent:

```
public interface IObjectConnectorEditor : IObjectConnector
public interface IObjectConnectorConfigurator : IObjectConnector
...
```

and create objects while inheriting from the existing Components and Connectors:

```
public class ObjectConnectorEditor : ObjectConnector, IEditor
...
public class ObjectComponentEditor: ObjectComponent, IEditor
```

The problem now is: I would need to implement the IEditor-interface in both Editor-classes, which would be an awefull redundancy. But I cannot create an implementation of IEditor from which the objects would inherit, because I can only inherit from exactly one class in C#, so the following will not work:

```
public abstract class Editor : IEditor ...
public class ObjectConnectorEditor: ObjectConnector, Editor
```

What would you suggest as the best architectural solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Polity's answer, but if you really want to fake up multiple inheritance in C#:

Create Component, Connector, Edit, and Config as separate classes. Also create IComponent, IConnector, IEdit, and IConfig as separate, matching interfaces.

Now you can create ComponentConfig, implementing IComponent and IConfig, and just delegate the interface methods to private instances of Component and Config.

```
class ComponentConfig : IComponent, IConfig 
{
    private IComponent component;
    private IConfig config;

    public ComponentConfig() {
        component = new Component();
        config = new Config();
    }

    public ComponentMethod() { 
        return component.Componentmethod(); 
    }

    public ConfigMethod() {
        return config.ConfigMethod();
    }

}
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I'm going to use your suggestion, because the only overhead seems to be the delegation to the private instances. But from your words, it seems to me that you consider this (faking multiple inheritance) the second best approach. I do not know how the architecture for the approach Polity suggest could look like. Can you point me to an example?

Answer (score 3):

Remember single responsibility. You want your objects to be all information containers, connectors and editors?

I would propose a different design where these responsibilities are split up, with a class hierarchy that represents Objects, Connectors, Components and Editors.

Comment: Hi Polity, thanks for the reply! The point is, that an object is connector *and* edit ... or component *and* config .. and so on. I want to design the class structure in a way, that I need to implement the methods and properties for connector, component, edit and config only once.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, improve your naming: in this context `Object` has no meaning, call it `Node`. You're using your nodes in two different contexts, so it's reasonable to have an `IEditorNode` interface and a `IConfiguratorNode` interface. If these share some methods, it's reasonable to have a super-interface, so they are declared only once. So far we have:

```
interface INode {
}

interface IEditorNode : INode {
  int f(); // Needed later
}

interface IConfiguratorNode : INode {
}
```

These interfaces serve a double purpose: they make it possible to use `Component`s and `Connector`s interchangeably and they limit the methods available to the `Editor` and to the `Configurator` to what they actually need to see. Note that there's no need to use interfaces if neither of these reasons are relevant.

You have two types of nodes: `Connector` and `Component`. If these don't have specific methods that are used either in the Editor or in the Configurator but not in both, just define them as classes and make them implement both `IEditorNode` and `IConfiguratorNode`. Otherwise it may make sense to distinguish these through interfaces:

```
interface IEditorComponent : IEditorNode {
}

interface IConfiguratorComponent : IConfiguratorNode {
}
```

Make the `Component` class implement both these interfaces:

```
class Component : IEditorComponent, IConfiguratorComponent {
}
```

The `Connector` class is analogous.

Unfortunately C# doesn't support multiple inheritance of implementation, so your only alternative to factor together common `Editor` or `Configurator` functions is to put them in separate classes, give `Component` and `Connector` a private attribute of each of these classes and delegate the implementation:

```
class EditorHelper {
  public int f() {
    return 42;
  }
}

class Connector : IEditorConnector, IConfiguratorConnector {
  EditorHelper eh;

  public Connector() {
    eh = new EditorHelper();
  }

  public int f() {
    return eh.f();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nicola, thanks for your answer! In my project, I use more speaking names, I just simplified here for more clarity. I think I will be going to use the idea of heaving an implementation for specific interfaces (IEditor, IConfigurator, IComponent, IConnector) and use the implementations as private variables.